# Does negation affect grammatical aspect in this Gide sentence?

Tags: verbes

The question is on the highlighted words in this passage from La porte étroite by André Gide.  The "je" in it is Alissa.

> Grande émotion, en passant rue de Paris avant-hier, de voir, à la devanture de M…, bien indiscrètement étalé, le livre d’Abel que tu **m’avais annoncé**, mais à la réalité duquel je **ne parvenais pas** à croire. Je n’ai pu y tenir ; je suis entrée ; mais le titre m’en paraissait si ridicule que j’hésitais à le dire au commis ; j’ai même vu l’instant où j’allais ressortir de la boutique avec n’importe quel autre ouvrage. Heureusement, une pente pile de Privautés attendait le client, près du comptoir – où j’ai jeté cent sous, après m’être emparée d’un exemplaire, et sans avoir eu besoin de parler.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Suppose that Alissa had brought herself to believe (succeeded in believing) in the reality of the book.  Which of the following would express that?

> (A) . . . le livre d’Abel que tu m’avais annoncé, et à la réalité duquel j'**étais parvenue** à croire
>   (B) . . . le livre d’Abel que tu m’avais annoncé, et à la réalité duquel je **parvenais** à croire

2. If the answer to 1 is (A), then it would appear that negation affects the form of verb. Gide has:

> (G) . . . le livre d’Abel que tu m’avais annoncé, mais à la réalité duquel je **ne parvenais pas** à croire

Plus-que-parfait for the affirmative vs. imparfait for the negative version.  Why is that when, presumably, the same thing is being affirmed or negated?

3. If the answer to 1 is (B), why should we use the imperfect when the action spoken of is a "completed" action, just like *m’avais annoncé*?
4. Could one have said:

> (G') . . . le livre d’Abel que tu m’avais annoncé, mais à la réalité duquel je **n'étais pas parvenu** à croire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd say (A) means what you think, but I could see (B) being correct too, with a nuance in meaning. In (A) she believed it and it's done, but in (B) she managed to believe it but she's not *that* convinced and could stop believing at any time.
   (By the way it's "*parvenu**e**"*)
2. It's not that hard to understand that negation changes the tense, it's not a yes/no, symmetrical thing here. If you try but you don't succeed, you can keep trying, but if you succeed, you stop trying. It's the same reason you can say "*I'm trying but it doesn't work*" but not "*I'm trying and it works*", you have to say "*I **tried** and it works*". That is not related to how tenses work, but more about what the opposite of "not succeeding" implies.
3. I'll still cover that question, juste in case. "*Annoncer*" is a definite action you don't do during an extended period, but "*parvenir à y croire*" **in (B)** is not a completed action. Something like "I managed to believe it, for now".
4. Yes, but a different tense has a different meaning. This would imply the whole thing is farther in the past. "*Je ne parvenais pas à y croire*" means she's still trying to believe it, while with "*je n'étais pas parvenue*" she stopped trying and has moved on.

I hope that covers it all.

Answer (score 1):

The "imparfait" denotes a lasting state or a habit while the "passé composé" is used for a short action which is now completed.  "Ne pas parvenir" is a long lasting state, while "parvenir" is a transition which is now done.